# get via fql or graph api the facebook insights for traffic from notifications

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-apps, facebook-insights

I would like to automatically download the facebook insights related to traffic coming from notifications (to be specific just app notifications, not users).
Obviousley i can see the data from the Insights Dashboard (under Insights -> Traffic -> Notifications). I can also export the CSV from there.
But i need to access those data autoamtically, using FQL or the graph api.
It does not seem to be possible from i can see in the documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/insights/
Did anyone manage to access those data not from the Insights Dashboard?

Thanks

Comment: This would indeed be very useful